# Redirect to request url with modified parameter

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route like `/users/HGB8J/` and I want to do a 301-redirect if users don't use only uppercase letters for the `userTag`. I am trying to write a middleware which would ensure the uppercased `userTag` for multiple routes as seen below.

**My question:**

How can I do a redirect to the "original url" just with a modified parameter (the uppercased `userTag` in this case)

```
function ensureTagIsUppercased(req, res, next) {
    let userTag = req.params.userTag
    if(userTag === userTag.toUpperCase())
        next()

    // How can I build the same URL just with the uppercased userTag?
    let url = ''
    return res.redirect(301, url)
}
router.get('/:userTag', ensureTagIsUppercased, profile)
router.get('/:userTag/refresh', ensureTagIsUppercased, refreshProfile)
```

**Examples:**

User requests => https://example.com/users/HGB8J/ the request can pass

User requests => https://example.com/users/hgB8J/ it should be redirected to https://example.com/users/HGB8J/

User requests => https://example.com/users/hgB8J/refresh it should be redirected to https://example.com/users/HGB8J/refresh

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I came up with so far is to replace the original parameter in the baseUrl with the upperCased parameter. However this could lead to conflicts where it would uppercase other parts of the URl which are not part of my parameter.

```
let redirectPath = req.originalUrl.replace(req.params.userTag, userTagUpperCased)
return res.redirect(301, redirectPath)
```